# maven build error

Tags: java, linux, maven-2

I am very much new to maven. I downloaded the maven 2.0.11 version and installed it on my 32bit redhat linux along with JDK 1.4

After installation I have configured the proxy settings. When I try to run command `mvn install` downlaod of some repository(org) is successful but then it fails with build error as below :

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------   
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR   
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------   
[INFO] Cannot execute mojo: resources. It requires a project with an existing pom.xml, but the build is not using one.   
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------   
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch   
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------   
[INFO] Total time: 16 second
```

What does this error mean ? and what configuration I am missing ?
How can I downlaod the complete repository ?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you got pom.xml in the current directory? Execute "pwd" and "ls" in your working directory and paste output.

Comment: What I also don't get: Why would you install Java 1.4 and Maven 2.0.11 *now*? Java 1.5 is already EOL (see http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/ ) and yet you install an *older* version? Why not 1.6? Maven 2.2.1 has also been around 6 months or more, yet you go with a 2.0.x version. Why? Other developers *have to* use old software because they *have to* support legacy platforms, but why would one voluntarily use outdated technologies?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error usually means there is no `pom.xml` in the current directory where
you're trying to build.

The ant `build.xml` has references to a few pom files:

```
<xmlproperty file="${IMPERIUS_SVN_MODULES}/pom.xml"/>
<property name="POM_XML_FILE" value="${basedir}/pom.xml"/>
<property name="POM_XML_URL" value="${IMPERIUS_SVN_TRUNK_REPOSITORY}/pom.xml?view=co"/>
<get src="${POM_XML_URL}" dest="${POM_XML_FILE}"/>
```

Can you check that these are being pulled down when you run `ant`? If not, try downloading the pom manually from [here](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/incubator/imperius/trunk/pom.xml?view=co) and save it in the same directory as `build.xml`. Then try running `ant` again.

Comment: ??? How is this relevant? How does the question have anything to do with ant ???? Maybe you should write a sentence about why you give an ant answer to a maven question ??? Yes, I know, I read the comments to the other answer, but if you just read the question and the answer it makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 2):

Your Maven installation seems correct. However, to be run, the Maven command must be run in the directory where the `pom.xml` file is located. It seems that you don't have any `pom.xml` in the current directory.

The `pom.xml` file describes your project, and it is the basis of Maven 2. Read [the official documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/index.html) to get more information about this file.

Note that Maven also provides the [Archetype plugin](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/), which can be used to create a brand new project of a specific type (Java project, Web application, Hibernate, Spring, and so on). The archetype will create the default structure and some files (including the `pom.xml`) for this type of project. This plugin is the only case of Maven usage without a `pom.xml` file.

Comment: I am trying to build imperius sources :http://incubator.apache.org/imperius/community/contribute.html .                              I am simply following the step : "simply download the build file(build.xml) to a directory where you'd like to create the Imperius distribution and run ant from that directory. The build will use the Subversion client to pull down the latest files from the Imperius repository" During the build maven execution is failing .. There is no mention of pom.xml ??? How to resolve this ?

Comment: @hits_lucky Did you run the Maven command in the directory that contains the pom.xml?

Comment: Inside the ant build file they are calling maven commands. This is the ant build file : http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/incubator/imperius/trunk/build.xml?view=co

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue today as well. Under the configurations for Maven Build I had changed the Base directory: from e.g.

> C:/local/project/MyProject

, which was set by using the *Browse File System...* to

> ${workspace_loc:/MyProject}

set by the *Browse Workspace...* and was able to build the project.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you are not in the same directory as in the pom.xml is located. Maven project looks for `pom.xml` at first to build the project . Please make sure you are building the project from the directory where the `pom.xml` is and also be careful that pom.xml should be correct hierarchy wise else it will not load some basic structure of project or will create one in internal folder.